# Updating Linked List on Action event

Tags: java, swing, linked-list, awt

Basically I need to update a list on the event of enter being pressed from a text box with a value inside it e.g. Birmingham

Once enter is pressed, the value from the text box is searched through a ready made library, and the matching values are displayed in the linked list

Comment: Take a look at [How to write action listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for tips and ideas

Answer (score 1):

All that you need to register corresponding `ActionListener` on your text box.